# Spark Streams: Parallelization when consuming from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-streaming

my S3 objects will contain this type of data in different files

```
metric-name start-time          stop-time           request-id
service-A   12/06/2017 19:00:00 12/06/2017 19:01:00 12345
service-B   12/06/2017 19:01:00 12/06/2017 19:02:00 12345
service-C   12/06/2017 19:02:00 12/06/2017 19:03:00 12345
```

I want to run a Spark Streaming job that will aggregate this data into something like the following

(Basically it takes the start time of one metric and the stop time of another to create an aggregated metric)

```
metric-name             start-time          stop-time           request-id
service-A to service-B  12/06/2017 19:00:00 12/06/2017 19:02:00 12345
service-A to service-C  12/06/2017 19:00:00 12/06/2017 19:03:00 12345
```

I have a few questions though:

1. how do Spark jobs parallelize when consuming from S3? Do they read
   from different files simultaneously?
2. Is there a way to determine how such partitioning occurs?
3. In a more traditional programming model I'd probably create a map
   structure and use this to create the aggregated metrics...how can I
   achieve this bearing in mind the data could be spread across
   multiple S3 objects?

Comment: _Is there a way to determine how such partitioning occurs?_ - Spark doesn't have any special rules for S3. Splits are computed in the same way as it was a file system. If files are compressed with unsplitable format it will read whole files, otherwise it will split according to the rules for a format.

Comment: just a question: why do you want to implement it with spark streaming? why not to use spark-core with reduceByKey style aggregation?

Comment: Because I want it to be real-time instead of a batch process that will produce delayed results

Comment: I am trying to understand.. What is the reason for doing metric only for `A-B` and `A-C` but not `B-C`? How we identify start and end points in A, B and C ?

Comment: We could do B to C as well.